# calling another mxml function in other mxml file in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

i have defined some functions in a component mxml file let us say

`addbutton()`

now i want to call this function in main mxml file.
How can i do that.

best regards

Comment: Please research before posting basic questions.

Comment: I completely disagree.  When some component.mxml has some function in it and we want to call that function from someDifferent.mxml, this is hard to understand for beginners.  In my opinion umar made a reasonable request; researching this myself and having a surprisingly difficult time getting past this kind of clutter to find a real answer.  It will be a real relief to see Flash/Flex fade from use for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var anyname:addGroup = new addGroup();
anyname.addGroupe();
```

This will work.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

```
yourComponentId.addButton()
```

Comment: i have addGroup named component mxml now it contain a function addGroupe i want to call this function in main.mxml so i am doing addGroup.addGroupe it wont work.

Comment: is your function declared as public? when are you calling the function? Is your component instantiated?

Comment: i am using a button which calls a function on click , this function is defined as usual in fx:script and it calls this adGroup.addGroupe function. and yes it is public. it wont recognize what is addGroupe

Comment: why did this answer got -1?! The answer is valid.